# How do the splits points in a decision tree within Random Forest are taken/selected? (Base on which criteria?)

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-trees, cart

I checked many posts to figure out how random forest (RF) *learning* algorithm (an ensemble of many decision trees (DT) constructed by [Rain forest algorithm](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/31959/69263)) within bagging select **split points** at each leaf. There are some close questions which are have not been answered in this matter: [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75044832/how-do-the-splits-in-a-decision-tree-classifier-work), [ref2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/490185/240550). I know that some python package use [Splitter](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/397482/240550) implementation, probably based on [*Gini* impurity](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/89952/the-notation-of-splitslabel-under-random-forest) as they asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/539999/240550) for how it works as well as its [reason](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/89455/69263) to use in DT. For example, [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn) package uses *CART algorithm* to build RF [Ref1](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/68164/69263) [Ref2](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/109238/69263).
Also, I found below posts without further explanation about how **split points** are selected as criteria over dataset exactly:

> "*... Distance is not a factor with trees - what matters is whether the value is greater than or less than the split point, not the distance from the split point.*" [ref](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/665/69263)

> *... unlike linear/logistic regression, RF doesn't work by distance (they work with finding good split for your features), so NO NEED for One-Hot Encoding.* [ref](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/29706/69263)

Considering an example for [continuous target variables](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/52912/69263) through dataframe, once I watched carefully [StatQuest: Random Forests Part 1 - Building, Using and Evaluating](https://youtu.be/J4Wdy0Wc_xQ), and the best I could find with a true example is this [video](https://youtu.be/v6VJ2RO66Ag):

Knowing that the decision trees in the random forest are trained on different subsets of the training data ([using random features (*"feature bagging"*)](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/20304/69263)), I used and developed the [bootstrapped tables or sub-dataframe (resampled but with replacement)](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/61908/69263) in the explanation for 1st DT for better understanding and find relationships in the video example:
[image: img]
Here I see 1st DT just both randomly selected variables from data:

```py
x1 =< 4.9  #selected from `id=0` only
x0 =< 4.3  #selected from `id=0` only
```

So how they selected from `id=0` only?

I follow other bootstrapped tables:
[image: img]
Then I see 2nd DT just both randomly selected variables from data:

```py
x3 =< 4.6 #selected from `id=4` only
          # No x2 ??
```

So how they selected just from `id=4` only? Is it a random `id`?
I follow other bootstrapped tables:
[image: img]
Then I see 3rd DT, just both randomly selected variables from the data:

```py
x2 =< 4.1 #selected from `id=0` or `id=2` not clear?
x2 =< 4.1 #selected from `id=4`
```

Here is not clear to me why twice `x2` was involved in the 3rd tree without involving variable `x4`?

Finally, I see the fourth DT in the video, from both randomly selected variables from the data:

[image: img]
Then I see 3rd DT, just both randomly selected variables from the data:

```py
x1 =< 4.4 #selected from `id=3` 
x2 =< 6.1 #selected from `id=1`
```

So Qs:

- Based on which criteria *split points* are taken/selected for randomly selected pair variables?
- Again, here twice, `x1` was involved in the 4th tree without involving variable `x1`? Does it make sense?
- I'm unsure what I marked based on my finding; explain the "criteria" of `x > y`, and if so, how it works. Sometimes both randomly selected pair variables are involved in DT; sometimes not.
- I didn't get based on the pick split points `y` via `id=#`? Is there any rule, or is it just randomly picked? Can we say [it is relative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75044832/10452700)?
- Final decision is being made when the end leaf is `0` or `1`?

---

My pythonic implementation:

```py
#Generate data in the video example
import pandas as pd
d = {'x0' : pd.Series([4.3, 3.9, 2.7, 6.6, 6.5, 2.7], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
     'x1' : pd.Series([4.9, 6.1, 4.8, 4.4, 2.9, 6.7], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
     'x2' : pd.Series([4.1, 5.9, 4.1, 4.5, 4.7, 4.2], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
     'x3' : pd.Series([4.7, 5.5, 5.0, 3.9, 4.6, 5.3], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
     'x4' : pd.Series([5.5, 5.9, 5.6, 5.9, 6.1, 4.8], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
     'y'  : pd.Series([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
#    x0   x1   x2   x3   x4    y
#0  4.3  4.9  4.1  4.7  5.5  0.0
#1  3.9  6.1  5.9  5.5  5.9  0.0
#2  2.7  4.8  4.1  5.0  5.6  0.0
#3  6.6  4.4  4.5  3.9  5.9  1.0
#4  6.5  2.9  4.7  4.6  6.1  1.0
#5  2.7  6.7  4.2  5.3  4.8  1.0

#Create RF model

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
%matplotlib inline
import random
from pprint import pprint
import pdb
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

#Create and fit RF model with 4 trees
rf  = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=4, random_state=0)
rf.fit(df.iloc[:,0:5], df.iloc[:,-1])
#len(rf.estimators_) #4
```

```py
#Plot the trees for monitoring split points in 1/4 of trees (1st tree)
tree.plot_tree(rf.estimators_[0])
```

[image: img]

```py
#Plot the trees for monitoring split points in 2/4 of trees (2nd tree)
tree.plot_tree(rf.estimators_[1])
```

[image: img]

```py
#Plot the trees for monitoring split points in 3/4 of trees (3rd tree)
tree.plot_tree(rf.estimators_[2])
```

[image: img]

```py
#Plot the trees for monitoring split points in 3/4 of trees (4th tree)
tree.plot_tree(rf.estimators_[3])
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking multiple questions, so I will try to answer them all, and then give a piece of code that I used for exploration.

First, here is a summary of how a [RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) works:

1. it creates subdataset from the original, using **random** subsampling of samples and features.
2. it fits [DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) based on each subdataset.

   - to select the best threshold from the subfeatures that leads to the best split, multiple thresholds are evaluated using a `criteria`. See the first answer for details.
3. perform a majority vote or an average prediction based on all decision trees prediction

***Based on which criteria *split points* are taken/selected for randomly selected pair variables?***

For every feature available for a node<sup>1</sup>, separation criteria are computed for multiple thresholds. They are multiple possible implementations for them:

- use all data values as thresholds (which seem to be used in the video)
- use the middle points of all successive data values (used by [sklearn here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx#L368))

So using your data and [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn) convention, if `x1` is tested with all samples, the following thresholds are evaluated: `[3.65, 4.6, 4.85, 5.5, 6.4]`. When it is evaluated,  separation criteria are computed as explained in this [mathematical formulation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#mathematical-formulation). Then the threshold with the best separation criteria is selected.

See this **[very nice video about decision trees](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_L39rN6gz7Y)** and how ther are built. (9:57 for continuous data + gini impurity computation)

<sup>1</sup> *So it doesn't compare multiple features. It is not relative. If you need such behaviour, you could add `x-y` as an input feature*

**`plot_tree` interpretation** (EDIT)

`value=[2,4]` in `plot_tree` means that you have currently 6 samples<sup>1</sup>. 2 from class 0 and 4 from class 1. In your `rf.estimators_[3]`, this dataset has been splitted with feature 0 because it has been evaluated as the best split (minimum impurity with `gini=0.444`). 3 samples from class 1 went to the right leaf, and the others went to the left node before being splitted again by feature 3.

<sup>1</sup> *[The number of values doesn't sum to the number of samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103507/why-does-this-decision-trees-values-at-each-step-not-sum-to-the-number-of-sampl) because of bootstraping.*

***Again, here twice, x1 was involved in the 4th tree without involving
variable x1? Does it make sense?***

> I didn't get based on the pick split points `y` via `id=#`? Is there any rule, or is it just randomly picked? Can we say [it is relative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75044832/10452700)?

I think, if I understand correctly, that you're confusing the build from the video and the one from [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn). They are different because of the **random** subsampling, both on samples and features. To generate new samples to be used for DecisionTreeClassifier, see this [sklearn `_generate_sample_indices()` function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/8c9c1f27b7e21201cfffb118934999025fd50cca/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L123). In the video, samples id are not the same.

So, `x1` is used in the 4th tree of the video, but not in the 4th tree in your code.

***I'm unsure what I marked based on my finding; explain the "criteria" of x > y, and if so, how it works. Sometimes both randomly selected pair variables are involved in DT; sometimes not.***

Multiple criteria can be used. In [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn), 3 are possible:

- gini (default)
- entropy
- log_loss

Here are their [mathematical formulation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification-criteria).

At each node, a lot of thresholds are evaluated and criteria computed. For example, in the video, for the 1st tree in the 1st node, the following subdataset is used:

[image: subdataset]

For `x0`, they are 3 different values, so 3 thresholds are evaluated. For `x1`, 4. That makes 7 entropy (or gini) criteria values. The best is then selected.

***Final decision is being made when the end leaf is 0 or 1?***

Once again, they are multiple implementations. The [original paper](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/randomforest2001.pdf) used a majority vote, but as mentioned in the [sklearn doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#random-forests):

> In contrast to the original publication [B2001], the [scikit-learn](/questions/tagged/scikit-learn)
> implementation combines classifiers by averaging their probabilistic
> prediction, instead of letting each classifier vote for a single
> class.

I hope it helps.

**SAMPLE CODE**

Here is a sample code that you can execute with your code, and that shows the 4 `DecisionTreeClassifier()`s build from the subdatasets. Note that I did not find an explicit function to extract the sub-feature indexes. Note that if you plot the trees, they are all similar to the ones built from `RandomForestClassifier()` except for the 3rd, but its first node has the same best gini separation. So the difference comes from a different order somewhere; I did not figure out where...

```py
from sklearn.ensemble._forest import _generate_sample_indices
sub_features_indexes = [
    [0, 1], # pair features (x0 , x1) based on video tutorial
    [2, 3], # pair features (x2 , x3) based on video tutorial
    [2, 4], # pair features (x2 , x4) based on video tutorial
    [1, 3]  # pair features (x1 , x3) based on video tutorial
]

for i in range(4):
    seed = rf.estimators_[i].random_state
    boostraped_samples = df.loc[_generate_sample_indices(seed, 6, 6)].sort_index()
    
    #sliced frame based on video tutorial
    boostraped_samples_dfslice = boostraped_samples[boostraped_samples.columns[[sub_features_indexes[i][0],sub_features_indexes[i][1], -1 ]]] 
    display(boostraped_samples_dfslice)

    dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=seed)
    dtc.fit(boostraped_samples.iloc[:,sub_features_indexes[i]], boostraped_samples.iloc[:,-1])

    tree.plot_tree(dtc)
    plt.show()
```

**EDIT**

> So how they selected just from id=4 only? Is it a random id?

When evaluating the value of id=4, so 4.6, as a threshold, the labels are perfectly separated, so there is no need to go further. But, that doesn't mean `x2` was not evaluated. It was, but it doesn't separate the labels better than choosing `4.6` as the threshold on feature `x3`

Comment: Thanks for your insightful input. I slightly edited your answer, including your proposed developed code, to adapt it to discussed tutorial video example and keep this thread consistent. I also include one of the Qs that you forgot *I didn't get based on the pick split points `y` via `id=#`? Is there any rule, or is it just randomly picked? Can we say [it is relative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75044832/10452700)?* your answer covered the 1st & 2nd parts already: *In the video, samples id are not the same.*  and *random subsampling, both on samples and features.*

Comment: Based on an interesting thread, I found out that *"scikit-learn's Random Forest uses bootstrap for 3 different things: **items**, **features**, **splitting**"* [ref](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/16809/69263) where it could explain the part you couldn't figure it out. What about the 3rd part: *Can we say [it is relative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75044832/10452700)?* Would you elaborate about it possibly?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! you're right, randomly selecting the best split explains the different results. I elaborated a bit about "*can we say it is relative*", is it enough ?

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the edit, Alternatively, I wanted to ask if you know what it means `gini=0.0` in leaves where I plotted in the post. Apparently, it shows the end of a branch or the *end-leaf* within the branch, but I'm unsure if it is the right interpretation!

Comment: `gini=0` means that the impurity of the split is 0 (the minimum), so you have a perfect split (only one label). That means that it is automatically a leaf, because you can't split further.

Comment: Note that `value=[2,4]` in `plot_tree` means that you have currently 6 samples. 2 from class 0 and 4 from class 1. In your `rf.estimators_[3]`, this dataset has been splitted with feature 0 because that has been evaluated as the minimum impurity (`gini=0.444`). 3 samples from class 1 went to the right leaf, and the others went to the left node before being splitted again by feature 3.

Comment: I added a video in the answer that I find very insighful and might help

Comment: Oh Ok, then `X[0]<= 5.4` means in the [4th tree plot](https://i.imgur.com/tnXKcHb.jpg) means `df` has been split based on feature `x0` due to minimum impurity of (`gini=0.444`). Are you sure that `value=[2,4]` means 6 samples: `2` samples for class y=0 & `4` samples for class y=1, while within the leaf printed `samples=4`? It seems as long as using `bootstrap=True` doesn't show the *total* `samples` [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56104317/10452700). I just saw you addressed it in the footnote in the new update.

Comment: Yes, based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71644712/10452700) in RF, which by default `bootstrap=True` due to bootstrap sampling with replacement including duplicate ones), in fact, `samples=4`  reflects **unique samples** and `value=[2,4]` reflects all samples count including **duplicated ones** so is `2+4`=6.

Comment: May I ask you to check this [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/121124/69263) related to RandomForest
if you had free time to debug ?